# What is the best way to process a batch file in AWS so it can be published to multiple subscribers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a .csv file with a number of transactions that is generated daily. I would like to separate and publish each record as a message. I was considering saving the .csv file into an S3 bucket, which would trigger a Step Function workflow where a Lambda function retrieves the file and passes each line to another Lambda function, which in turn transforms the line into a message and publishes it to an SNS topic, which destination systems are subscribed to. I wanted to check if this was a) feasible and b) the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I would skip the intermediary lambda function, it does not provide any value / speedup, just have the first lambda publish all the SNS messages directly. And you do not need a StepFunction but just a single, ordinary lambda that is subscribed to S3.

Comment: Is the processing time-consuming or resource-intensive? How many lines are in the CSV file? Could you process the file completely in one Lambda function within 15 minutes? Please edit your question to provide more details.